# - LISP - how to create a bitmap file by script?

Tags: bitmap, lisp, common-lisp, creation

I'm a newbie here so please be soft with me =)

I'm trying to develop a script in LISP  (sorry, no other language) to create a bitmap file.
I went on different web site about the bitmap format, but my concern is about the procedure itself.

Using LISP, (and perl / awk, my environment is Linux RHEL5) i can only create a text file with the 'regular' ASCII codes (i mean printable / displayable).

My issue is about the chars that are not printable.
For example, if i want to put in the bitmap header the hexadecimal chain 00 00 00 00, what would be the corresponding ASCII code?

how can i print them in a file?

Thanks a lot for your help and clarifications!

best,

P-chan

Comment: Hi pilou, if you have been given the correct answer to your question, please 'accept' the answer. This both gives the answerer recognition for their work but also lets others know that the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 6):

Common Lisp can read/write any binary data you like.

You need to open the stream as a binary stream and the use functions like `READ-BYTE`, `WRITE-BYTE`, `READ-SEQUENCE` and `WRITE-SEQUENCE`.

Example:

```
(with-open-file (s "temp-bytes" 
                   :direction :output
                   :element-type 'unsigned-byte)
  (write-byte 101 s))
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from bytewise operations (see Rainer's answer), you can use a library like `opticl`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers guys. I'm going to try ! cheers!